# How to dynamically take the value using Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a form along with a add new row button. Each row consist of different fields. Now I have already defined an ArrayList of the above fields in the command bean. My problem is that how can I dynamically take in new values and bind it to my bean during the runtime. I want to add a dynamically generated list and post it back to save it in the database. How to achieve this?

For example I have form with three text areas and there is an add button. Now when I click the add button there is a dynamic generation of the three text fields on the front end. and now I have to bind it to my bean where I have declared and arraylist for this three text areas. Now how should I achieve this. My ArryList is as follows..

```
private ArrayList<CommText> commText;
```

and the class CommText has these three variables

```
class CommText
{
private String text1;
private String text2;
private String text3;

//Getters and Setters...

}
```

Comment: an example may be useful

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman I have mentioned a small eg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a javascript `Ajax` framework such as JQuery to post this to your `Controller`, which can in turn update your collection.

Which version of spring-mvc / webflow are you using?